# Invalid ViewState only in IE 10

Tags: c#, .net, viewstate, internet-explorer-10

**Solved: IE 10 seems to have issues with handling the null character. Because we are generating large amounts of code server side, buffering was resulting in a NULL character in the List Item data, which ended up corrupting the ViewState (NULL is not a valid base64 char). I noticed this because the corruption was not occurring on small data sets**

**I have resolved the issue by setting `Response.Buffer = false` while the list items are being generated. Other possible solutions I dabbled with:**

**- `ListBox.DataSource = new DataView(dataTable)` and `ListBox.DataBind()` for the listbox data. This resulted in clean data, but would require a stored procedure change in my case**

**- Gracefully clear the buffer so that the NULL appears outside of the `<option>` elements**

After doing a lot of research, I am still stuck with an invalid viewstate error in our web application.

To summarize:

- I've used a ViewState examiner that I found online, but it is unable to parse the ViewState so it hasn't helped. The second pair returns "Unreadable data"
- Consistent in IE 10 ONLY. Does not show up in any other browser
- Works fine in Document Mode IE9 Standards (we are working on supporting IE10 Standards)
- The two main fields on the page (two listboxes) will not work with `EnableViewState="False"`, so a workaround regarding that is not a desired option.
- After examining the source of the page, I am seeing a `NUL` character in the Base64 string.

My guess is that the ViewState is being truncated at the NUL character, and the error is thrown because the expected ViewState is not the same as what is received. However, I'm stuck on how to verify this, narrowing down what is causing the corrupt data, and how to resolve the issue.

#### UPDATE: I have found a NUL character in the data set, removing this character from the ViewState resolves the issue... Looking at the database, the data looks completely fine. Imagine the `[NUL]` is a legitimate null char

Viewstate:

```
...pZmUFBTE[NUL]4NjoxZxAFD1RJQUEt...
```

One of the options in the listbox:

```
<option value="201:1" title="Pr[NUL]emier 20">Premier 20</option>
```

#### Now I suppose I need to track down where this corruption is occurring?

Code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem liListItem;

    clsGLOBALGASubscription clsGAS = new clsGLOBALGASubscription(lngSubID);
            DataTable dataTable = clsGAS.ListSelectedProducts(Session["GAID"].ToString().Trim());

    if(dataTable == null)
    {

        lstbAvailable.Items.Add("There are no products available for your account.  Please contact your administrator.");
        btnAdd.Visible = false;
        btnAddAll.Visible = false;
        btnRemove.Visible = false;
        btnRemoveAll.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            if(Session["SelectedProducts"] != null && Session["SelectedProducts"].ToString().Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    string strConcatIDs = dataRow["CompanyID"] + ":" + dataRow["SeriesID"];
                    liListItem = new ListItem(dataRow["Company"] + " - " + dataRow["Series"], strConcatIDs);
                    liListItem.Attributes.Add("title", String.Format("{0} - {1}", dataRow["Company"], dataRow["Series"]));

                    foreach(string subString in Session["SelectedProducts"].ToString().Split(delimiters))
                    {
                        if(subString == strConcatIDs)
                            if (xraeList)
                                {

                                    foreach (string CarrierHealthItem in XraeCarrierList)
                                    {
                                        string[] CarrierInforArray = CarrierHealthItem.Split(':');
                                        if (CarrierInforArray[0].ToString() == dataRow["CompanyID"].ToString())                                          
                                        {
                                            foundXrae = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (foundXrae)
                                    {
                                        liListItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red");
                                        liListItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontWeight, "bold");
                                        foundXrae = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                lstbSelected.Items.Add(liListItem);
                                bSelectedAlready = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (bSelectedAlready == false)
                        {
                            if (xraeList)
                            {
                                foreach (string CarrierHealthItem in XraeCarrierList)
                                {
                                    string[] CarrierInforArray = CarrierHealthItem.Split(':');
                                    if (CarrierInforArray[0].ToString() == dataRow["CompanyID"].ToString())                                           
                                    {
                                        foundXrae = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (foundXrae)
                                {
                                    liListItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red");
                                    liListItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontWeight, "bold");
                                    foundXrae = false;
                                }
                            }

                            lstbAvailable.Items.Add(liListItem);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bSelectedAlready = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else // ...no Selected Products, so just populate lstbAvailable
                {

                    foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                    {

                        liListItem = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(dataRow["Company"] + " - " + dataRow["Series"], dataRow["CompanyID"] + ":" + dataRow["SeriesID"]);
                        liListItem.Attributes.Add("title", String.Format("{0} - {1}", dataRow["Company"], dataRow["Series"]));

                        if (xraeList)
                        {
                            foreach (string CarrierHealthItem in XraeCarrierList)
                            {
                                string[] CarrierInforArray = CarrierHealthItem.Split(':');
                                if (CarrierInforArray[0].ToString() == dataRow["CompanyID"].ToString())
                                {
                                    foundXrae = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (foundXrae)
                            {
                                liListItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red");
                                liListItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontWeight, "bold");
                                foundXrae = false;
                            }
                        }
                        lstbAvailable.Items.Add(liListItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error:

```
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. ]
System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +90
System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +60
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +173

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: 10.128.3.10
Port: 44359
Referer: http://LTCarrierProduct.aspx?Title=Customize Carriers and Products&XraeValidation=Invalid
Path: /LTCarrierProduct.aspx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
ViewState: 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...]

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +177
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +11367569
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +11447671
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +56
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11441698
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11441214
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +269
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +167
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +625
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270
```

From ie.browsers on the server:

```
<browser id="IE6to9" parentID="IE5to9">
  <identification>
    <capability name="majorversion" match="[6-9]" />
  </identification>
  <capture></capture>
  <capabilities>
      <capability name="jscriptversion"          value="5.6" />
    <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported"    value="true" />
  </capabilities>
</browser>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting updated browser definition file into App_Browsers folder?

Comment: Added relevant lines from my ie.browser file, please let me know if that is relevant

Comment: I think so, but there could be other entries there - can you attach entire `ie.browser`file?

Comment: Added another update. I have tracked down a NUL character in the data that is causing the error. I am still unsure on how this data is being corrupted

Comment: So that [NUL] is not coming from DB? How/when does it appear on the form?

Comment: I have tracked the NULL characters down to buffering. The listboxes I am working with often have over 150+ items, each with a decent amount of data. With small data sets, I am not seeing the NUL characters within the data. However, they are throughout the resulting source HTML in roughly 16,000 character increments. I have stepped around the issue by disabling the Response Buffer while generating the list items. Unfortunately, this has shown light on a larger issue: IE10 does not play nice with the unicode null character. Other browsers do not stumble, but IE10 results in broken html

Comment: My initial issue has been resolved, I have updated the question with my findings. I suppose I will create a new question regarding the larger issue at hand with IE10 and unicode null char. Thank you Yuriy!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but this is the additional section we have in our `ie.browser`:

```
 <browser id="IE5to9" parentID="IE">
    <identification>
        <capability name="majorversion" match="^[5-9]|[1-9]\d+" />
    </identification>

    <capture>
    </capture>

    <capabilities>
        <capability name="activexcontrols"     value="true" />
        <capability name="backgroundsounds"    value="true" />
        <capability name="cookies"             value="true" />
        <capability name="css1"                value="true" />
        <capability name="css2"                value="true" />
        <capability name="ecmascriptversion"   value="1.2" />
        <capability name="frames"              value="true" />
        <capability name="javaapplets"         value="true" />
        <capability name="javascript"          value="true" />
        <capability name="jscriptversion"      value="5.0" />
        <capability name="msdomversion"        value="${majorversion}${minorversion}" />
        <capability name="supportsCallback"    value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsFileUpload"  value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsVCard"       value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"     value="true" />
        <capability name="tables"              value="true" />
        <capability name="tagwriter"           value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
        <capability name="vbscript"            value="true" />
        <capability name="w3cdomversion"       value="1.0" />
        <capability name="xml"                 value="true" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
```

Solved a lot of issues for us. Give it a try.